# Which variables can be accessed with the ${...} syntax in a Struts tag in a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl, el

I'm getting a little bit frustrated since I can't find out which variables I can access with the `${...}` syntax in a Struts tag, placed in a JSP page.

As an example I've got the following code:

```
<c:set target="${status.menue}" property="activeMenuePath" value="whatever" />
```

Where does the object `"status.menue"` have to be defined in order to can be accessed with a dollar sign and braces. Is it defined in another struts tile or in the form?

Comment: Question saved my life as you mentioned 'dollar' and 'braces' which makes it searchable with google as google does not let you search for '${'...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be placed in any of the page, request, session or application scopes using respectively [`JspContext#setAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), [`ServletRequest#setAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), [`HttpSession#setAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) or [`ServletContext#setAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29). You normally do that either directly or indirectly inside a Servlet. MVC frameworks do that indirectly, usually configureable by giving the model object a "request", "session" or "application" scope.

The [Expression Language (EL)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) will access them using [`JspContext#findAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29).

This all is by the way unrelated to Struts. It's just a legacy MVC framework which is built on top of the JSP/Servlet API. The `<c:set>` is not a [Struts](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/struts/info) tag as well, it's a [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) tag.

Comment: This answer was important for me since I wanted to know which different contexts there are and how to use them. Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if it is required but I had to add `<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>` to my jsp for these expressions to work